# Micro SD card stopped functioning after inserted when phone on. Android and Windows recognize the card, but can't read it. Can I recover my data?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, data-recovery, partitions

Android and Windows say I have to format the card in order to access it, but I don't want to lose my data. I have tried to read the card with Recuva and iCare Card Recovery Pro, but they can't access the card either. The card is partitioned, I don't know why. Disk Management, at Control Panel, shows one partition of 16mb and other of 7,2gb.

Is there a way I can recover my data?

Android version: 6.0

The card was used as internal storage.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Can you please [edit] your post and fill some gaps: What Android version is running on your device? If 6 or above, did you use the card as "internal storage" (aka "adoptable storage")?

Comment: Or did you encrypt the card?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers! I made the changes on the post.

Answer (score 0):

"The card was used as internal storage" - This means it is encrypted and tied to the decryption key on your device. If your device is already rooted, you Might be able to access the key and use [this](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html?m=1) to access it, it requires Linux and some terminal use, Windows will not be useful for this operation.

If you removed this card while the device was powered up and the card mounted, which it will always be as internal storage, you likely corrupted the drive's file system, and recovery of data from a damaged, encrypted file system is extremely difficult and often requires professional forensic data recovery if the decryption key is available, it's impossible without it, and those services are rather expensive and can be thousands of dollars in some cases.

When a drive is adopted as internal storage, it is reformatted to Linux ext4 file system and encrypted, it is intended to never be removed from the device, ever, unless you go through the process to convert it back to portable storage. The encryption used is very secure, without the decryption key it is generally considered impossible to access the data even if the file system is completely intact and undamaged.

So basically I am saying you're most likely out of luck... The chances of recovery of the data is near zero.